# PHP doesn't receive data sent from $http.post

Tags: php, angularjs

I have a function inside an AngularJS controller that let me send POST data to a PHP page (it should be for authentication)

```
$scope.submit = function () {
    $http.post(api + 'login.php', $scope.user)
};
```

This function is called from this HTML code

```
<div>
    <span ng-show="isAuthenticated">{{welcome}}</span>
    <form ng-show="!isAuthenticated" ng-submit="submit()">
        <input ng-model="user.username" type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username" />
        <input ng-model="user.password" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
    <div>{{error}}</div>
    <div ng-show="isAuthenticated">
        <a ng-click="logout()" href="">Logout</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using Firebug inside Firefox I can see that auth page is called and POST data is sent correctly

[image]

Problem raises within my auth PHP code: I try to retrieve POST data, but array is empty.
I've also tried to write content in a file and I can confirm array is empty (file contains [])

```
$userdata = $_POST;
file_put_contents("login.txt",json_encode($userdata)."\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

What's wrong with my code?
I've also tried changing from POST to GET (using `$http.get`), but $_GET array is empty too...

Comment: Can you post the output of `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: It's what I wrote in the file: it's [ ]

Comment: can you then post `var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"))`?

Comment: or `var_dump(http_get_request_body()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Angular sends data over as json, not as form data, to retrieve it you can do something like:

```
$_JSON = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
```

Comment: Never in my life I could have imagined this... I've lost hours for this. Thank you so much!

Comment: Never in my life would I have imagined this either. Good to know for future projects as angular is about to be added to the company library list. You may have just saved me hours.